# @EnableEurekaServer, @EnableConfigServer, @EnableAdminServer and @EnableZuulProxy walk into a bar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am having trouble building a Spring Boot + Spring Cloud application that is combining Zuul, Eureka server, Config server and Admin server in one unique application.

If you are already thinking: "Why on earth, this is breaking micro services concepts, etc.." I totally agree. This question is about the feasibility to make it happen, not to ask if it is a good idea to do it, thank you for your understanding.

Does anyone know how to make it happen? Some solution with Spring 2.1.0 + Spring Cloud Finchley or above will be great.

The code is obviously very straightforward:

`

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

`

The pom is also simple:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.M3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

With an also straightforward config file:

```
spring.application.name=question
server.port=8090

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8090/eureka
spring.boot.admin.context-path=/admin
spring.cloud.config.server.prefix=/config

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=...
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths=...
```

[...]

The closest I got was to use 2.0.6 + Finchley:

```
2018-12-08 13:20:10.515  INFO 13078 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-12-08 13:20:10.519  WARN 13078 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [RxIoScheduler-1 (Evictor)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-12-08 13:20:10.534  INFO 13078 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-08 13:20:10.536 ERROR 13078 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method reactor.retry.Retry.retryMax(J)Lreactor/retry/Retry; but it does not exist. Its class, reactor.retry.Retry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/aaa/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/addons/reactor-extra/3.1.7.RELEASE/reactor-extra-3.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/reactor/retry/Retry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/aaa/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/addons/reactor-extra/3.1.7.RELEASE/reactor-extra-3.1.7.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of reactor.retry.Retry


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I would suggest running mvn dependencies:tree on your project to see what is bringing in the reactor-extra module.  It looks like one of those spring libraries are using different versions of that library?  If that's the case, you might need to investigate if there are versions of the libraries that use the same version of the reactor-extra and manually declare them instead of using the default versions defined by the starter modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need version 2.0.4 of spring boot admin. You're using the latest (2.1.1) which is not compatible with the rest of Spring libraries you're using.

Comment: Yes, just tried, it is working.

Some follow up issues on Zuul not being able to get the route.serviceId from Eureka, while properly working with the route.url, but I believe it is a different story.

Thanks a lot